# Julia automatically generate functions and export them

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

I want to automatically generate some functions and export them automatically. To have some concrete example, lets say I want to build a module, which provides functions that take a signal and apply a moving average/maximum/minimum/median... to it.

The code generation already works:

```
for fun in (:maximum, :minimum, :median, :mean)
  fname = symbol("$(fun)filter")
  @eval ($fname)(signal, windowsize) = windowfilter(signal, $fun, windowsize)
end
```

Giving me functions

```
maximumfilter
minimumfilter
...
```

But how do I export them automatically? e.g. I would like to add some code to the above loop like

```
export $(fname)
```

and have each function exported after creation.

Comment: Does `eval(Expr(:export, fname))` work? I use something like that in `SymPy`. Not sure it is the best way though.

Comment: @jverzani Tom's answer is interesting, but your comment should probably be the accepted answer due to the (incredible) simplicity and the fact it will work on v1.0. If you post it then I'll upvote it for sure.

Comment: I think this was an issue with an old version of julia, where `Expr(:export, fname)` == `:(export $fname)` did not hold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could consider using a macro:

```
module filtersExample

macro addfilters(funs::Symbol...)
  e = quote end  # start out with a blank quoted expression
  for fun in funs
    fname = symbol("$(fun)filter")   # create your function name

    # this next part creates another quoted expression, which are just the 2 statements
    # we want to add for this function... the export call and the function definition
    # note: wrap the variable in "esc" when you want to use a value from macro scope.
    #       If you forget the esc, it will look for a variable named "maximumfilter" in the 
    #       calling scope, which will probably give an error (or worse, will be totally wrong
    #       and reference the wrong thing)
    blk = quote
      export $(esc(fname))
      $(esc(fname))(signal, windowsize) = windowfilter(signal, $(esc(fun)), windowsize)
    end

    # an "Expr" object is just a tree... do "dump(e)" or "dump(blk)" to see it
    # the "args" of the blk expression are the export and method definition... we can
    # just append the vector to the end of the "e" args
    append!(e.args, blk.args)
  end

  # macros return expression objects that get evaluated in the caller's scope
  e
end

windowfilter(signal, fun, windowsize) = println("called from $fun: $signal $windowsize")

# now when I write this:
@addfilters maximum minimum

# it is equivalent to writing:
#   export maximumfilter
#   maximumfilter(signal, windowsize) = windowfilter(signal, maximum, windowsize)
#   export minimumfilter
#   minimumfilter(signal, windowsize) = windowfilter(signal, minimum, windowsize)

end
```

when you load it, you'll see the functions are automatically exported:

```
julia> using filtersExample

julia> maximumfilter(1,2)
called from maximum: 1 2

julia> minimumfilter(1,2)
called from minimum: 1 2
```

See [the manual](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/) for more info.

Comment: For me this does not work, I got an "syntax: extra token "(" after end of expression" at the line export $(esc(fname)).

Comment: Are you on 0.3?  I'm using a 0.4 development version, so it's possible/likely that the syntax has changed since 0.3.  I don't have 0.3 installed... can anyone else help?